# user-register.tpl.php error message not showing up

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

In drupal 6 I have made a custom user-register.tpl.php form, and when the username or email already exists, the box gets red but the error message "your email is already registered" does not show up.  Neither does the message when they successfully register "your login information has been mailed to you"

How can I fix this? 
my code is

```
    <div id="registration_form">
    <div class="field">
    <?php  print drupal_render($form['name']); // prints the username field
    ?>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
    <?php
    print drupal_render($form['mail']); // print the email field
    ?>
    </div>
   <div class="field">
   <?php
    print drupal_render($form['submit']); // print the submit button
   ?>
   </div>
   <?php
    print drupal_render($form['timezone']);
    print drupal_render($form['form_build_id']);
    print drupal_render($form['form_id']);
    ?>
    <?php
    drupal_set_message('< pre >'. var_export($variables,TRUE) .'< /pre >');
    ?>
```

thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can print messages made by the **drupal_set_message()** method directly in your **page.tpl.php** with the variable **$messages**. So in your **page.tpl.php**, make sure that this line exists :

```
<?php print $messages; ?>
```

Now if you need to print each error separataly, you have to use **[form_get_error($element)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_get_error/6)** where **$element** is the name of your input

Comment: Great! that works I was putting that code in the user-register.tpl.php and user-login.tpl.php pages and it didnt show up.  putting it in the page.tpl.php works .  thanks